# what is use case of @ResponseBody in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

what is the usage of  `@ResponseBody` in Spring MVC? 
Because Can't I access that without that?

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/employees" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<JSONObject> employees( @SessionAttribute("emp") Employee emp, Model model ) {
```

Comment: *Can't I access that without that *: what does that mean? Have you read the javadoc of this annotation? Have you read the Spring MVC documentation about it (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)? What is unclear? And if you haven't: why?

Comment: thanks Nizet. Actually I'm new to this environment. If I mention any thing wrongly, many apology for that. I'm going to read and try to understand the doc which you send. Once again many thanks for the reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ResponseBody annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object.

Comment: then if I didn't add that annotation, is it possible to receive response from client ?